# Trouble using the same image for multiple objects

Tags: python, animation, python-3.x, pygame, glob

I'm making a game with Pygame and I'm trying to animate asteroids that get hit with a bullet. The animation works fine if there's just one asteroid type on the screen. I run into trouble when there's two identical asteroids on the screen. It seems that the first one on is the only one that uses my animation.

For example, say the game spawns two small asteroids, these are the exact same and I'm using glob.glob to get the 4 animation images, then I'll just use those images to create a little animation by looping over them. This works with one of the asteroids, the other will not play the animation. I'm thinking it must be because only one object can use specific images at any one time?

I'm sorry for the terrible explaination.

Here's the asteroid class I have and the call to create the animation:

```
class Asteroid(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, screen, size):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.screen = screen
        self.size = size
        self.pos_x = random.randint(100,900)
        pos_y= random.randint(100, 700)
        self.pos_y = -pos_y
        self.vel_y = 3
        self.update_main = True
        self.animation_path = ""

        #load the image then put it above the screen, ready to drop
        if self.size == "small":
            self.asteroid_image = pygame.image.load("asteroid_small.tga")
            self.animation_path = "C:/Programming/Stupid Games/Alien Invasion/animations/asteroid_small/*.tga"
        elif self.size == "medium":
            self.asteroid_image = pygame.image.load("asteroid_medium.tga")
            self.animation_path = "C:/Programming/Stupid Games/Alien Invasion/animations/asteroid_medium/*.tga"
        elif self.size == "med_large":
            self.asteroid_image = pygame.image.load("asteroid_med_large.tga")
            self.animation_path = "C:/Programming/Stupid Games/Alien Invasion/animations/asteroid_med_large/*.tga"
        elif self.size == "small_med":
            self.asteroid_image = pygame.image.load("asteroid_small_med.png")
        elif self.size == "small_1":
            self.asteroid_image = pygame.image.load("small1.tga")
            self.animation_path = "C:/Programming/Stupid Games/Alien Invasion/animations/small/*.tga"
        else:
            self.asteroid_image = pygame.image.load("asteroid_large.tga")
            self.animation_path = "C:/Programming/Stupid Games/Alien Invasion/animations/asteroid_large/*.tga"

        #make the asteroid transparent
        corner = self.asteroid_image.get_at((0,0))
        self.asteroid_image.set_colorkey(corner, RLEACCEL)

        #randomly rotate the image
        self.new_asteroid_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.asteroid_image, random.randint(0,340))

        self.rect = self.new_asteroid_image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x, self.rect.y = ((self.pos_x, self.pos_y))
        self.start_animate = False
        self.times = 0

        #load the asteroid animation
        self.animation = glob.glob(self.animation_path)
        self.animation.sort()
        self.animation_pos = 0
        self.animation_max = len(self.animation)-1
        self.animation_speed_init = 50
        self.animation_speed = self.animation_speed_init

    def update(self):
        #if asteroid has left the screen, place it back to the top
        if self.rect.y > 900:
            pos_y = random.randint(100,500)
            self.rect.y = -pos_y
            self.rect.x = random.randint(100,900)

        self.rect.y += self.vel_y
        self.position = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
        self.screen.blit(self.new_asteroid_image.convert(), self.position)

        if self.start_animate == True:
            self.animation_speed += 25
            if self.animation_speed > 60:
                self.update_main = False
                self.new_asteroid = pygame.image.load(self.animation[self.times])
                corner = self.new_asteroid.get_at((0,0))
                self.new_asteroid.set_colorkey(corner, RLEACCEL)
                self.new_asteroid_image = self.new_asteroid
                self.animation_speed = 0
                self.animation_pos += 1
                self.times += 1

            if self.times > self.animation_max:
                self.kill()

    def start_animation(self):
        self.start_animate = True



#create asteroids at the start of the game
if keys[K_SPACE]:
    game_over = False
    player = Space_Ship("space_ship.tga", screen)
    asteroid_small = Asteroid(screen, "small")
    asteroid_large = Asteroid(screen, "large")
    asteroid_medium = Asteroid(screen, "medium")
    asteroid_med_large = Asteroid(screen, "med_large")
    asteroid_group.add(asteroid_small, asteroid_large, asteroid_medium, asteroid_med_large)
    player_group.add(player)
    score = 0



#add asteroids after the game has started
if len(asteroid_group) < difficulty:
    random_asteroid_number = random.randint(0,5)
    if random_asteroid_number == 0:
        #large asteroid
        asteroid_large = Asteroid(screen, "large")
        asteroid_group.add(asteroid_large)
    elif random_asteroid_number == 1:
        #medium asteroid
        asteroid_medium = Asteroid(screen, "medium")
        asteroid_group.add(asteroid_medium)
    elif random_asteroid_number == 2:
        #medium large asteroid
        asteroid_med_large = Asteroid(screen, "med_large")
        asteroid_group.add(asteroid_med_large)
    elif random_asteroid_number == 3:
        #small medium asteroid
        asteroid_small_med = Asteroid(screen, "small_med")
        asteroid_group.add(asteroid_small_med)
    elif random_asteroid_number == 4:
        #small_1 asteroid
        asteroid_small_1 = Asteroid(screen, "small_1")
        asteroid_group.add(asteroid_small_1)
    else:
        #small asteroid
        asteroid_small = Asteroid(screen, "small")
        asteroid_group.add(asteroid_small)



#bullet - asteroid collision
collisions = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(bullet_group, asteroid_group, True, False)
if collisions != None:
    for i in collisions.values():
            for sprite in i:
                channel2.play(asteroid_audio)
                if sprite == asteroid_large:
                    score += 3
                    sprite.start_animation()
                elif sprite == asteroid_small_1 or sprite == asteroid_med_large or sprite == asteroid_medium or sprite == asteroid_small:
                    score += 1
                    sprite.start_animation()
                else:
                    score += 1
                    sprite.kill()
```

Comment: Where do you create your new Asteroid objects in the code?

Comment: Sorry, I've added them in now.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is the problem, but you should load all pictures at start of the game, and use them accordingly in creation, instead of loading them from hardrive during game

Comment: Are you using a [sprite sheet](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Spritesheet?parent=CookBook) ?  And you can load the animation once, re-using the surface for all asteroid instances.

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't be sure because the bit where you call update is not shown, I have a few ideas of why it is doing what it is. It seems that the second asteroid's update is not being called. This could be for several reasons. The first reason is if you do not implement groups to update you asteroid. Basically, if you only call your single instance of the asteroid, the second one will not do anything, even show up on the screen. If this is the case, you will need to make a group, perhaps a render updates group but even a list would be fine. This would mean you could do something like:

```
asteroids.update()
```

or

```
for asteroid in asteroids:
    asteroid.update()
```

the above two codes assume that you have some kind of grouping of asteroids, called asteroids.

Another possible problem, if you are implementing groups, is if the second asteroid is not getting added to this group. If you tell it to add itself to the group in the **init** function, this problem will not be there, however, if you call it outside of this function, you may not be doing so when you make your second asteroid. To address this problem just move the part where you add the asteroid into a group that will be updated to the **init** function of asteroids.